# jQuery custom slider show or hide navigation buttons

Tags: jquery

I have built a custom jQuery slider (I know about Cycle etc but want to use a custom one).

It allows a user to navigate a slider using both a pager and next and previous buttons which I have managed to get working.

However because my slider does not loop (intentional by design) I would like to hide and show the next and previous buttons when the user has reached the first or last slides.

To do this I have created a function that runs when a user clicks either a button or pager and checks what to show or hide. But this is where I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

This is the fiddle for the slider: http://jsfiddle.net/2WeMT/

The closest I have got working so far is:

```
if ($('div.slideshow > div:last').is(':visible')) {
                        $('.next').fadeOut();
                    } else {
                        $('.next').fadeIn();
                    } if ($('div.slideshow > div:first').is(':visible')) {
                        $('.previous').fadeOut();
                    } else {
                        $('.previous').fadeIn();
                    }
```

But it doesn't show the correct buttons when in the middle pages and it sometimes gets confused and hides and shows the wrong buttons.

Also tried adding this to fix the middle page issue but again causes problems:

```
if ($('div.slideshow > div:visible').prev(':hidden')) {
                        $('.previous').fadeIn();
                    }
                    if ($('div.slideshow > div:visible').next(':hidden')) {
                        $('.next').fadeIn();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add to the next button

```
if($('.slideshow div:last-child') === $('.slideshow div:visible')){
    $('.next').hide();
}
```

add to prev

```
if($('.slideshow div:first-child') === $('.slideshow div:visible')){
    $('.previous').hide();
}
```

Comment: Also they need to fade in and fade out

Answer (score 0):

This does work though:

```
if ($('div.slideshow > div:first-child').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.previous').hide();
                }
                else {
                    if ($('div.slideshow > div:visible').prev(':hidden')) {
                        $('.previous').show();
                    } else {
                        $('.previous').hide();
                    }
                }


                if ($('div.slideshow > div:last-child').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.next').hide();
                } else {
                    if ($('div.slideshow > div:visible').next(':hidden')) {
                        $('.next').show();
                    } else {
                        $('.next').hide();
                    }
                }
```